# Comparing Model types Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, compare, laravel-5.4

I receive a single model. This model can be of two types. Say Either It can be `App\Models\User` **OR** `App\Models\Resource`

I want to check which type it is ? Currently I am using `instanceof` but no luck.

```
public function someFunction($result)
{
    //result can be either User model or Resource model.

    if( $result instanceof App\Models\User)
    {
       //do soemthing for user.
    }
    else{
       //do something for resource.
    }
}
```

Comment: when you do a `dd($result)` what do you get?

Comment: @Bara'ayyash, it is one of the eloquent model (user OR resource). Btw, check answer by Sandeesh, That was my mistake `typehinting` class model name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You path to class should be `\App\Models\User`.

```
use App\Models\User;

public function someFunction($result)
{
    //result can be either User model or Resource model.

    if($result instanceof User) {
        //do something for user.
    } else {
        //do something for resource.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeesh, It works. Mistake with `typehinting` model. Thanks again.